# android Calculator app using recursion

Tags: java, android, calculator

Here is the MainActivity java file for my calculator app:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private String numString = "";
EditText editTextView;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    editTextView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textView);
}

//when number buttons are clicked.
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    button = (Button) v;
    numString += button.getText().toString();
    editTextView.setText(numString);
}

//operation buttons which will also add a space before and after the operator.
public void onButtonSpaceGenerator(View view)
{
    button = (Button)view;
    numString += " ";
    numString += button.getText().toString();
    numString += " ";
    editTextView.setText(numString);
}

public void onClear(View v){
    numString = "";
    editTextView.setText("");
}

public ArrayList<String> createArray(ArrayList<String> arrayList){
    String tempString = "";
    int tempInt = 0;
    int tempIndex = 0;
    int[] array = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < numString.length(); i++) {
        if (numString.substring(i, i + 1) == " ") {
            array[tempInt] = i;
            tempInt++;
        }
    }
    for(int i: array){
        tempString = numString.substring(tempIndex, i);
        Log.d("arrayList!!!!", tempString);
        arrayList.add(tempString);
        tempIndex = i;
    }
    return arrayList;
}

public void equals(View v){
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList1 = createArray(arrayList);
    double total = calcResult(arrayList1);
    editTextView.setText(Double.toString(total));
    numString = "";
    arrayList.clear();
    total = 0;
}


public double calcResult(ArrayList<String> aL){
    double tempNum = Double.parseDouble(aL.get(0));
    aL.remove(0);
    if(aL.size() >= 1) {
        String operator = aL.get(0);
        aL.remove(0);
        if (operator.equals("+"))
            return tempNum + calcResult(aL);
        if (operator.equals("*"))
            return tempNum * calcResult(aL);
        if (operator.equals("-"))
            return tempNum - calcResult(aL);
        if (operator.equals("/"))
            return tempNum / calcResult(aL);
    }
    return tempNum;
}
```

}

---

And i'm not sure why, and I've tried debugging and reviewing the code many times, but still i'm unsure as to why my array List keeps on raising an indexoutOfBounds and would really appreciate any advice regarding what i'm missing or doing incorrectly:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3679)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4203)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17189)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3674)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4203)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17189)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
        at com.example.android.calculatorrecursion.MainActivity.calcResult(MainActivity.java:79)
        at com.example.android.calculatorrecursion.MainActivity.equals(MainActivity.java:70)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3674)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4203)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17189)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4950)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have a break condition in your recursion. You try to always get the first element of the List and THEN check if the List is empty. Your recursion will run forever or throw an Exception, because your list is empty.

This is one solution I can think of:

```
public double calcResult(ArrayList<String> aL) {
    if (aL.isEmpty()) { //Break condition
        return -1; //Or whatever you like to show an error
    } else {
        double tempNum = Double.parseDouble(aL.get(0));
        aL.remove(0);

        if (!aL.isEmpty()) { //Break condition
            String operator = aL.get(0);
            aL.remove(0);

            if (operator.equals("+"))
                return tempNum + calcResult(aL);
            if (operator.equals("*"))
                return tempNum * calcResult(aL);
            if (operator.equals("-"))
                return tempNum - calcResult(aL);
            if (operator.equals("/"))
                return tempNum / calcResult(aL);

            return tempNum;
        }else{
            return tempNum;
        }
    }
}
```

I would recomend you would use a Queue instead of an ArrayList, because you are only going to get the first element of the List and add new elements at the end of it - which is exactly what a Queue does.